Why does my gas fireplace occasionally fail to shut off at the set temperature?
I have a thermostatically controlled gas fireplace that is about 4 years old and the issue is that the most of the time it works properly, set it at 72° and the flame turns off at 74º+/-, but sometimes the flame continues to burn and the temperature continues to 78° or greater before I manually turn it off.
I have replaced the controller and the thermostat (appearance is like the Skytech 1001t/LCD but I don't think it's the Skytech brand) and there are no changes, it continues on occasion to heat without turning off.
I don't think the controller or the remote is the issue at this point in time and the remote is 2 1/2 - 3' away from the receiver. I don't know of any other remotes/ phones that could cause the signal interference but not positive. Also, refreshed the batteries when I lit the fireplace a few days ago, so I am baffled at what it could be or if you have experienced this issue prior.
What would be your recommendation for the next step?
